# Java Garbage Collection Latency Spikes on service restart

Tags: java, web-services, garbage-collection

We have a Java Web Service for which the Garbage Collection latency spikes up transiently for a day or two on each service restart. The latency comes back to normal on its own without any actions being taken.

More Info:

- Average Garbage Collection count is unchanged
- Usual Garbage Collection Latency ~ 75 milliseconds
- Garbage Collection Latency after service restart ~ 800 milliseconds
- The Service does not have any special Caching mechanism
- Overall Heap Memory Usage Graph is unaffected and stable
- Other service metrics like CPU Utilization, Latency, Errors are
  normal and stable.

Is this a known/common for Java Web Services?

Comment: how did you measure Garbage Collection latency?
what webserver software do you use?

Comment: We have a internal tool that creates graphs on Java Garbage Collection latency metrics